# ElasticSearch fails to start with `Unable to create java_pid1.hprof` error

Tags: linux, ubuntu, elasticsearch

After I resized my disk and restarted the ElasticSearch service it fails to start:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid1.hprof ...
Unable to create java_pid1.hprof: Permission denied
```

And after that I see a few errors, most likely as a result of the error above:

```
[DATETIME,864][ERROR][o.e.t.n.Netty4Utils      ] fatal error on the network layer
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4Utils.maybeDie(Netty4Utils.java:141)
    at org.elasticsearch.http.netty4.Netty4HttpRequestHandler.exceptionCaught(Netty4HttpRequestHandler.java:76)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:296)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeExceptionCaught(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:275)
```

What could be wrong after the disk resize and the service restart?

Comment: I have a similar issue, are you running it inside a docker container? Or did you eventually fix it?

Comment: had to restart the container and lose all the data

Comment: any solution to this (apart from restarting and loosing data)??